# Show number of answers accepted

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

Ever wish you could tell more about a user's acceptance rate than just the percentage? Sure, you can hover over the acceptance rate to view the number of questions asked and the number of accepted answers, but who has time for that these days? Instead, just use my handy-dandy script, and you will be able to see that information right there beside the user's accept rate. It's that easy!

#### Download

[Install](http://userscripts.org:8080/scripts/source/62156.user.js) | [View source](http://userscripts.org:8080/scripts/review/62156)

#### Platform

Tested on Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 9.0, on Windows 7. Requires Greasemonkey on Firefox.

#### License

Do whatever you want, as long as you don't sell it or claim you wrote it. If you make any cool modifications, let me know!

#### Source

It seems that userscripts.org is dying. Here is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           accept rate details
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @description    Shows more details of accept rate on Stack Overflow sigs.
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://superuser.com/*
// @include       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include       http://serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://meta.seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://askdifferent.com/*
// @include       http://meta.crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

  function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }; 

  with_jquery(function($) {
      var regex = new RegExp("([\\d]+) of ([\\d]+)");

      $(".post-signature.owner > div").each(function() {
        if($(this).text().indexOf("accept rate") > 0) {
          var matches = this.title.match(regex);
          if(matches.length == 3)
            $(this).text($(this).text() + " (" + matches[1] + "/" + matches[2] + ")");
        }
      });
    }
  );
})();
```

Comment: This is the kind of things that should be already implemented in StackExchange ;)

Comment: This is broken in latest stable Firefox on Windows 7.  Also is broken in all Firefox versions on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @ThomasWard it is working for me on AskUbuntu, here's a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OgYtF.png  Do you have any other user scripts installed that might be modifying the user profile card somehow?

Comment: @Kip the only other script I'm running that affects that same box is your script which shows absolute timestamps: http://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time.  I've got other mods such as pro-forma comments, and a couple of others, but they dont modify the user profile card at all.

Comment: I should add they work well together in **Kubuntu**.  The same cannot be said for Windows.