# Regional 12-hour timestamps

Tags: script, comments, posts

*This script is a modification of Kip's "[Display absolute timestamps (in local time)](https://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time)"; I have his permission to post this. Most of the credit for the script goes to him.*

### About

This script displays timestamps based on your timezone in 12-hour format. This is pretty convenient for anyone who doesn't want to convert UTC to their timezone. Requires Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey.

### Screenshot

[image]

## Download

[Install](https://rawgit.com/Sir-Cumference/3313ea9e22ed950f817d68321d16d69b/raw/2c5e81bb3a1365df549e5b6c098d1280309f075c/RT.user.js)

### License

Please ask [Kip](https://stackapps.com/users/5418/kip) and myself if you want to modify this for anything other than personal use.